# Can I join two data frames using one column in df1 and one of any values in a cell in df2?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm working with some geospatial data, `df_geo` and am have a CSV of values I'd like to join to the location data frame, called `df_data`.

My issue, however, is that there are multiple ways to spell the values in the column I'd like to join the two data frames on (region names). Look at the Catalonia example below, in `df_geo`: there are **6 different ways to spell the region name**, depending on the language.

[image]

My question is this: if the row is named "Catalonia" in `df_data`, how would I go about joining `df_data` to `df_geo`?

Comment: Is each row in your `DataFrame` unique to a region?

Comment: Yup! Each row in both `df_geo` and `df_data` represents data for a single region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rows are unique to a region, you can create a dictionary that maps any name in `'VARNAME_1'` to the index from `df_geo`.

Then use this to map the the names in `df_data` to a dummy column and you can do a simple merge on the index in `df_geo` and the mapped column in `df_data`.

To get the dictionary do:

```
d = dict((y,ids) for ids, val in df_geo.VARNAME_1.str.split(r'\\').items() 
                 for y in val)
```

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df_geo = pd.DataFrame({'VARNAME_1': ['Catalogna\Catalogne\Catalonia', 'A\B\C\D\E\F\G']})
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Catalogna', 'Seven', 'E'],
                        'Vals': [1,2,3]})
```

#### Code

```
d = dict((y,ids) for ids, val in df_geo.VARNAME_1.str.split(r'\\').items() 
                 for y in val)
#{'A': 1,
# 'B': 1,
# 'C': 1,
# 'Catalogna': 0,
# 'Catalogne': 0,
# 'Catalonia': 0,
# 'D': 1,
# 'E': 1,
# 'F': 1,
# 'G': 1}

df_data['ID'] = df_data.Name.map(d)
df_data.merge(df_geo, left_on='ID', right_index=True, how='left').drop(columns='ID')
```

#### Output:

```
        Name  Vals                      VARNAME_1
0  Catalogna     1  Catalogna\Catalogne\Catalonia
1      Seven     2                            NaN
2          E     3                  A\B\C\D\E\F\G
```

---

#### How the dictionary works.

`df_geo.VARNAME_1.str.split(r'\\').values` splits the string in `VARNAME_1` on the `'\'` character and places all the separated values in a `Series` of lists. Using `.items` on the `Series` gives you a tuple (which we unpacked into two separate values), with the first value being the index, which is the same as the index of the original `DataFrame`, and the second item being the

```
for ids, val in df_geo.VARNAME_1.str.split(r'\\').items():
    print(f'id:{ids} and val:{val}')
#id:0 and val:['Catalogna', 'Catalogne', 'Catalonia']
#id:1 and val:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

So now `val` is a list, which we again want to iterate over to create out dictionary.

```
for ids, val in df_geo.VARNAME_1.str.split(r'\\').items():
    for y in val:
        print(f'id:{ids} and y:{y}')
#id:0 and y:Catalogna
#id:0 and y:Catalogne
#id:0 and y:Catalonia
#id:1 and y:A
#id:1 and y:B
#id:1 and y:C
#id:1 and y:D
#id:1 and y:E
#id:1 and y:F
#id:1 and y:G
```

And so the dictionary I created was with y as the key, and the original DataFrame index `ids` as the value.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Small edit: maybe on my machine, byt dropping the ID column only works using `.drop(['ID'], axis=1)`

Comment: Oh yeah, must be an older version of pandas I believe when that happens

Comment: Hey @ALollz, is there any chance you'd mind describing the dictionary creation in a little more depth? I'm struggling a little to understand what's happening under the hood here. Would really appreciate it! Specifically, I think I'm a bit confused by how the ID number itself is being generated (I think I understand expanding the values in each row and adding them to the dictionary if they're not null)

Comment: @scrollex I updated the answer. You're right that the index was probably only luckily the same. I changed the answer to use `.items`, which will actually return the real index of the `Series`, instead of an integer index, which only happened to be the same. I also removed `expand=True` from `.str.split` so you no longer need to check `if y is not None`

Comment: Had a look, and seems like things are breaking now. `.items()` doesn't work over a Series; when I try using `.iteritems()`, the dictionary that's being created on my end has entries that looks like this: `'Catalu\xc3\xb1a|Catalogna|Catalogne|Catalonia|Catalunha|Catalunya|Katalonien': 68`

Comment: It’s should just be .items.